# Name 'main' not defined

Tags: python

I was trying to make tetris game using reinforcement learning. I get this name undefined error.Thanks in advance for the solution

```
class TetrisApp
...........
..........
other code
..........
..........
 def main(argv):
            cp = ''
            try:
                    opts, args = getopt.getopt(argv,"hc:c:",["computer_player="])
            except getopt.GetoptError:
                    print 'tetris.py -c[--computer_player] <True>|<False>'
            sys.exit(2)
            if len(opts) == 0 :
                    play(True)
                    for opt, arg in opts:
                            if opt == '-h':
                                    print 'tetris.py -c <True>|<False>'
                                    sys.exit()
                            elif opt in ("-c", "--computer_player"):
                                    cp = arg
                                    if cp == 'True':
                                            play(True)
                                    else:
                                            play(False)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv[1:])
```

Comment: Is `def main` inside the class TetrisApp? If this is the case, thats your problem. You could call `TetrisApp.main`

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] -- the shortest possible **working** code someone else can use to see the problem themselves. In this case, that calls for taking out references to code like `play` that aren't provided in the example, and ensuring that anything you provide that isn't literal code is either removed from the code section or formatted as a comment, to allow copy-and-paste testing. Also see "Tips for Trimming" at http://sscce.org/.

Comment: (Problem still happens after removing `getopt`? Then take `getopt` out. Problem still happens after making `main()` a function with only one line that calls something like `print("Made it to main")`? Then do that. Etc).

Comment: BTW, using `getopt` is making things much harder for you than they need to be. Look into [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) going forward.

Answer (score 0):

for calling Class methods Outside the class Use Class Object.

```
t=TetrisApp()
t.main(sys.argv[1:])
```

and use `self` in method `def main(self,argv):`